# Is there anyway I can pass a parameter to GSON JsonSerializer?

Tags: java, gson

I've got a `json` file which has got a `Date` field. I'm transforming this to a required Date format(dd/MM/yyyy) using `JsonDeserializer` and registering the class as a `TypeAdapter` in `GsonBuilder`. Now, I want to transform this field to  different date formats(say ISO8601) for different use cases. Instead of creating new `JsonDeserializer`'s for different date formats, Is there anyway I can pass date format as one of the parameters to `JsonSerializer` class to make it extensible.

Deserializer class:

```
public class DateDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Date> {
    private static final SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jsonDeserializationContext) {
        String dateString = jsonElement.getAsString();
        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(dateString)) {
            try {
                return DATE_FORMAT.parse(dateString);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
            }
        }
    }
```

GsonBuilder:

```
public static final Gson GSON = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new DateDeserializer())
            .serializeNulls()
            .create();
```

Comment: you can pass it in constructor like this:  `.registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new DateDeserializer("ISO8601 format here"))` if thats what you are looking.

Comment: Do you want to format the Date field differently based on different JSON?

Comment: @varren ha ha(facepalm situation), when you've been staring at your code for a long time, u miss out thinking on some very basic stuff, thanks for that.